# Is this shape feasible in CSS rather than clip-path

Tags: css, clip-path

I've just found out that clip-path is not recognized by firefox, and therefore I would like to re-create a shape similar to the one below but in CSS.

Is it possible?

Many thanks,

[image]

Comment: You ask if doing `clip-path` in CSS is possible (as opposed to SVG, I imagine) and then provide CSS that does exactly that. So what's your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `transform`'s `perspective` and `rotateY` values:

```
#elem {
   transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( -45deg );
}
```

```css
#cont {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 107px;
}
#cont img {
  transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( -45deg );
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/s7e/ffe" />
</div>
```